# Capitalization of nouns which are proper nouns!

Tags: nouns, proper-nouns, capitalization

Artificial Intelligence - AI. It is now a proper noun.

The sentence goes like -

> *"Artificial Intelligence can make better prediction of cholera outbreaks."*

The capital letters 'A' and 'I' are justified because they are the part of proper nouns.

What if I'm using the proper nouns as nouns. No capitalization therefore.

> *"Machines can now have artificial intelligence using what they can take better decisions themselves."*

Will it, by any means, be improper **not** to capitalize the letters *A* and *I*?

Comment: Who says 'artificial intelligence' is a proper noun?

Answer (score 2):

Proper nouns are capitalized; common nouns are not.  The same combination of words might be a proper noun or common according to meaning.

> In London, Green Park is a very green park.

The common noun park is used as part of the name of a particular park called "Green Park"

However, I doubt that "artificial intelligence" is a proper noun. It does not name a particular entity, rather it names a type of entity.  I would recommend the spelling "Artificial intelligence can make better prediction..." Unless you are referring to a specific computer program which is named "Artificial Intelligence". I wouldn't be very strict about this, it is an orthographic detail that I would pass over without comment.

The abbreviation is commonly written in all-capitals as "AI", this helps it to stand out and suggests the reading as "ei-ai" rather than as an acronym.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase 'artificial intelligence', abbreviated as AI, is a branch of study or research. It is, therefore, a common noun. Therefore you would not usually capitalise it according to English rules.

Now, if 'Artificial Intelligence' is the name of a device, software, hardware, app, website, etc. which would help people to determine symptoms of cholera and thus predict the possibilities, then you would capitalise it, since it then becomes a unique thing.